# Unable to reproduce Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm getting next error from crashlytics: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class TextView

Problem is that I'm not able to reproduce this issue and I can only guess why app has crashed while trying to inflate TextView. 
This TextView is in drawer_item_1.xml file which is menu item for application drawer.

This issue is reported only on devices running Android version 7.1.1 and 7.1.2 (Nexus 6P, Nexus 5x, Pixel XL and Sony Xperia X)

As I can see there is nothing suspicious here, it is simple TextView with some white text set to be bold, except layout_width is set to wrap_content and should be 0dp because of set layout_weight. Is it possible that this is causing this crashes?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="My String"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rbn_menu_arrow"
    />
```

Comment: I just tried on my phone with Android 7.1.1 and it inflates the layout normally. I just changed the color - how do you define that? But I guess that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The only source of error would be if the color is not properly defined. Check the color

Comment: @color/white is defined as #FFFFFF